# If the subscribed table is modified by rename column, the subscription will stop

Tags: cnosdb

#### Describe the bug

If the subscribed table is modified by rename column, the subscription will stop.
version:cnosdb 2.4.0, revision 842fc0e37a28327f14805f7ebe7ca1a85fca721c
mode:singleton

#### To Reproduce

```
db001 ❯ create subscription sub005 on db001 destinations all "127.0.0.1:8913" "127.0.0.1:8923" on air(time, station, pressure, visibility, visibility, temperature) filter_by where pressure < 50.0;
Query took 0.006 seconds.
db001 ❯ show subscription on db001;
+--------------+-------------------------------+------+
| SUBSCRIPTION | DESTINATIONS                  | MODE |
+--------------+-------------------------------+------+
| sub005       | 127.0.0.1:8913,127.0.0.1:8923 | ALL  |
+--------------+-------------------------------+------+
Query took 0.001 seconds.
db001 ❯ INSERT INTO air (TIME, station, visibility, temperature, pressure) VALUES (now(), 'XiaoMaiDao1', 56, 69, 41);
+------+
| rows |
+------+
| 1    |
+------+
Query took 0.005 seconds.
db001 ❯ select * from air order by time desc;
+----------------------------+-------------+------------+-------------+----------+
| time                       | station     | visibility | temperature | pressure |
+----------------------------+-------------+------------+-------------+----------+
| 2023-12-22T01:31:27.792337 | XiaoMaiDao1 | 56.0       | 69.0        | 41.0     |
db001 ❯ alter table air rename column visibility  to visibility_new;
Query took 0.005 seconds.
db001 ❯ select * from air order by time desc;
+----------------------------+-------------+----------------+-------------+----------+
| time                       | station     | visibility_new | temperature | pressure |
+----------------------------+-------------+----------------+-------------+----------+
| 2023-12-22T01:31:27.792337 | XiaoMaiDao1 | 56.0           | 69.0        | 41.0     |
| 2023-12-21T11:16:33.472047 | XiaoMaiDao1 | 56.0           | 69.0        | 41.0     |
db001 ❯ INSERT INTO air (TIME, station, visibility_new, temperature, pressure) VALUES (now(), 'XiaoMaiDao1', 56, 69, 41);
+------+
| rows |
+------+
| 1    |
+------+
Query took 0.007 seconds.
db001 ❯ select * from air order by time desc;
+----------------------------+-------------+----------------+-------------+----------+
| time                       | station     | visibility_new | temperature | pressure |
+----------------------------+-------------+----------------+-------------+----------+
| 2023-12-22T01:33:51.834820 | XiaoMaiDao1 | 56.0           | 69.0        | 41.0     |
| 2023-12-22T01:31:27.792337 | XiaoMaiDao1 | 56.0           | 69.0        | 41.0     |
| 2023-12-21T11:16:33.472047 | XiaoMaiDao1 | 56.0           | 69.0        | 41.
```

log as follow:

```
2023-12-22T09:38:11.475793000+08:00  INFO coordinator::subscription: Writing to subscriber failed: status: Internal, message: "column visibility not found in table air", details: [], metadata: MetadataMap { headers: {"content-type": "application/grpc", "date": "Fri, 22 Dec 2023 01:38:11 GMT", "content-length": "0"} }
2023-12-22T09:38:11.475874000+08:00  INFO coordinator::subscription: Writing to subscriber failed: status: Internal, message: "column visibility not found in table air", details: [], metadata: MetadataMap { headers: {"content-type": "application/grpc", "date": "Fri, 22 Dec 2023 01:38:11 GMT", "content-length": "0"} }
2023-12-22T09:38:13.752202000+08:00  INFO meta::service::single: watch notify watch.1001 3138.3138
2023-12-22T09:38:14.479289000+08:00  INFO coordinator::subscription: Writing to subscriber failed: status: Internal, message: "column visibility not found in table air", details: [], metadata: MetadataMap { headers: {"content-type": "application/grpc", "date": "Fri, 22 Dec 2023 01:38:14 GMT", "content-length": "0"} }
2023-12-22T09:38:14.479289000+08:00  INFO coordinator::subscription: Writing to subscriber failed: status: Internal, message: "column visibility not found in table air", details: [], metadata: MetadataMap { headers: {"content-type": "application/grpc", "date": "Fri, 22 Dec 2023 01:38:14 GMT", "content-length": "0"} }
2023-12-22T09:38:17.482346000+08:00  INFO coordinator::subscription: Writing to subscriber failed: status: Internal, message: "column visibility not found in table air", details: [], metadata: MetadataMap { headers: {"content-type": "application/grpc", "date": "Fri, 22 Dec 2023 01:38:17 GMT", "content-length": "0"} }
2023-12-22T09:38:17.482347000+08:00  INFO coordinator::subscription: Writing to subscriber failed: status: Internal, message: "column visibility not found in table air", details: [], metadata: MetadataMap { headers: {"content-type": "application/grpc", "date": "Fri, 22 Dec 2023 01:38:17 GMT", "content-length": "0"} }
2023-12-22T09:38:20.485558000+08:00  INFO coordinator::subscription: Writing to subscriber failed: status: Internal, message: "column visibility not found in table air", details: [], metadata: MetadataMap { headers: {"content-type": "application/grpc", "date": "Fri, 22 Dec 2023 01:38:20 GMT", "content-length": "0"} }
2023-12-22T09:38:20.485558000+08:00  INFO coordinator::subscription: Writing to subscriber failed: status: Internal, message: "column visibility not found in table air", details: [], metadata: MetadataMap { headers: {"content-type": "application/grpc", "date": "Fri, 22 Dec 2023 01:38:20 GMT", "content-length": "0"} }
```